# Implement AutomationPeer supporting Text pattern with dictionary suggestion in XAML Custom Control

Tags: xaml, c++-cx, microsoft-ui-automation

I am trying to modify [this example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Touch-keyboard-sample-43532fda) (the `TouchedTextBlock` control in particular) for a text editing `UserControl`. Unfortunately, the sample is far from adequate. The only thing it allows is for the software keyboard to show up when user taps on the control: the keyboard does not supply dictionary suggestion as user types. Also, it doesn't illustrate how my control should receive and process editing commands; for instance, if user picks a word suggested by the keyboard, how does my control gets the word and add it to the text? I added debugging code to track method calls and it seems that none of the [ITextProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.automation.provider.itextprovider.aspx), [IValueProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ee671565.aspx) and [ITextRangeProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.automation.provider.itextrangeprovider.aspx) implemented is called. So my questions are:

1) When are the method in the aforementioned interfaces invoked? Can anyone explain the workflow/interaction of the UI Automation mechanism?

I am so confused by many articles on MSDN. My rough understanding is that the keyboard is like a 'client' (executing in a separate process from the app) in the UI Automation framework and the `AutomationPeer` is like the 'server'. Somehow in this example, the keyboard client does not interact at all with my `AutomationPeer`; it only interacts with the entire app via supplying key events while it should specifically interact with the customized `AutomationPeer`. I would expect the following workflow:

- User taps on the control
- The control gain focus by calling `Focus`
- Upon gaining focus, the framework invokes `OnCreateAutomationPeer` to create my customized implementation of `AutomationPeer`
- Framework determines the patterns and control type, show software keyboard if `Text` pattern is detected and the text is not read-only
- **What really happens in the sample**: the keyboard seems to supply raw key events to the entire application.
   **What I expect**: the keyboard (remotely) 'invokes' my `AutomationPeer`'s methods to let users insert characters and words (and backspace, enter, ...) to my control.

2) Is there a sample illustrating how to provide suggestion?

*Please do not suggest me to use build-in controls such as `TextBox` or `RichEditBox`: I would have used them if they suit my need.*